# iptables recent module: remove entries older than

Tags: iptables, firewall

I am using `iptables` `recent` module:

```
-A INPUT -m recent --rsource --name PORTSCAN --set -j DROP
```

The above line adds offending IP addresses to `/proc/net/xt_recent/PORTSCAN`.

Now I am looking for a way how to periodically (cron job) check this list, and remove entries that are older than `n` hours.

I am using the option `xt_recent.ip_pkt_list_tot=1` with `recent`. That means, I don't keep multiple times when packet was seen. I only keep the last time packet was seen.

So the list `/proc/net/xt_recent/PORTSCAN` looks like this:

```
src=185.242.5.46 ttl: 240 last_seen: 4312349727 oldest_pkt: 1 4312349727
src=184.100.29.188 ttl: 57 last_seen: 4312673918 oldest_pkt: 1 4312673918
src=184.157.25.107 ttl: 57 last_seen: 4312086204 oldest_pkt: 1 4312086204
```

How can I periodically "purge" this list, so that I only keep entries that are less than `n` hours old?

Does `iptables` provide some way to do this? Or does this have to me done with some custom script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `--reap` is what you are looking for, from [iptables-extensions man page](https://man.archlinux.org/man/core/iptables/iptables-extensions.8.en), section about `recent`:

> `--reap`
> This option can only be used in conjunction with `--seconds`. When used, this will cause entries older than the last given number of seconds to be purged.

As of how it works, here is the [relevant source code part from Linux kernel](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/4b7ddc58e61ada82be1f47f82d5139f0ab2ba478/net/netfilter/xt_recent.c#L155).

Comment: I have seen the `--reap` option in the manual page aswell, but understood it as a way to remove given IP from the list. That means, the IP has to arrive in my firewall rules to be processed. But this is not what I am asking for. I need a way to process the already existing IPs in my list periodically, and remove entries older than `n`.

Comment: I'm confused - how do you think `--reap` works, step by step - and what are your expectations?

Comment: can you show me how I could use the `--reap` option, to go through my list (`/proc/net/xt_recent/PORTSCAN`) and purge IPs older than `n` ?